# How can I access the Taxonomy store using the Client Object Model?

Tags: development, client-object-model, managed-metadata

We are writing an Outlook plugin and need to create an overview of the available Managed Metadata term stores and terms from clients that connect to SharePoint. I have used the TaxonomySession to do this from programs that run on the server machine, but this class requires an SPSite in the constructor, which I get the impression it not available using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace (Specifically, the ClientContext class, which gives you access to a watered-down version of the server objects when not running on the server itself).

Are there anyone who has done this before who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client object model doesn't support working with the MMS, but you can use the webservice called TaxonomyClientService.